# Sending checkbox value through Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using C# and wish to be able to send either a "Yes" or No" through an email `StringBuilder` depending on whether a user has checked a checkbox (check being Yes, and left empty being No).

Shall I use a conditional operator?

```
string YesNo = chkYesNo.Checked ? "Yes" : "No";
```

*but*, aren't only checked boxes sent to the server? Is that correct? So, I would need a script to find out if it hasn't been checked.

*EDIT*:
my apologies, I am using webforms, with a codefile containing my string-builder

Comment: are you using WebForms?

Comment: Yes indeed. WebForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that conditional operator, as `WebForms` keeps controls data in it's states. `ViewState` is responsible for that.

It's always transferred to `Server`

I would personally create a method that translates `CheckBox.Checked` to `String` result or maybe even use `Enum` as it's more consistent than just a strings, or at least use constants, so "YES" and "NO" has single point of setting.

I think you should consider also creating a type that holds a value, something like `EmailModel` or something and use that instead of simple variables.

Comment: In the old .Net era, only checked items were sent to the server, this is where I was going wrong. Thanks for your help.